# dataframe manipulation with python

Tags: python

so I'm really new to python and the whole dataframe manipulation topic. What I'm trying to do is to ask the user for a min year and a max year, then list the name and year for the provided range. 
I have tried many different approaches, the last one I tried and though was going to be successful was this:

```
 yearInputMin = int(input("Please enter min year: "))
    yearInputMax = int(input("Please enter max year: "))

    for row in my_data:
        year = int(row['year'])
        if year <= yearInputMax and year >= yearInputMin:
            print
            year
```

I'm focusing more on the year aspect because that is the area I'm having most difficulty in.

Any ideas of how to achieve this?

Comment: What error are you seeing here? Also, the `year` line should be in the same line as the `print` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dataframes are very easy to search through with ".loc", try this:

```
yearInputMin = int(input("Please enter min year: "))
yearInputMax = int(input("Please enter max year: "))

my_data.loc[(my_data['year']<=yearInputMax)&(my_data['year']>=yearInputMin)]
```

more details on: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html